# clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-stdlib=libc++'

Tags: c++, cmake

I cannot find much information regarding this.
What can cause clang to specify this warning?

I have a dev machine which runs a cmake script and everything works fine. The very same cmake file is being executed on a build server the above message is being printed out all the time.

The build server is running clang3.8 while my dev machine is running clang4.
I cannot reproduce this problem with a simple solution either.
For instance, a simple main.cpp will not cause this error:

```
clang++ main.cpp -std=c++14 -stdlib=libc++
```

works just fine even on the build machine.

Any ideas why this might get printed?

This are the flags im using:

```
set(LIBRARY_RELEASE_OPTIONS "-Wall;-Wextra;-pedantic;-Wlong-long;-Wmissing-braces;-Wunused-function;-Wuninitialized;-Wunused-label;-Wunused-parameter;-Wdisabled-optimization;-O2;-std=c++14;")
add_library(${SHARED_LIBRARY_NAME} STATIC ${SERVER_SOURCE})                                             
target_compile_options(${SHARED_LIBRARY_NAME} PUBLIC "$<$<CONFIG:RELEASE>:${LIBRARY_RELEASE_OPTIONS}>")
```

Comment: Do you build with `-nostdinc++` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 no I don't, should I specify that as well?

Comment: You may have an option which makes `'-stdlib=libc++'` unused. `-nostdinc++` is one of that option.

Comment: Do you provide several `-stdlib=` in your command line ?

Comment: You should provide the problematic command line BTW.

Comment: @Jarod42 oh ok. I dont know if this is related but I'm building a static library with cmake, which I than link together with my other executable. I can't recall getting this message when I didn't build a static library. Removing stdlib doesn't work either so I'm stuck

Comment: @Jarod42 I have updated the post with the command

Comment: @Jarod42 I found out the problem, when I removed ccache, everything worked as expected... there are no more warnings. But I really want to use ccache

Comment: @Crippin I’ve always been afraid ccache would have bugs that made my code wrong. I thought it was just an unfounded superstition I’d get over when compile times got too bad, but maybe not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to silence the warning, add `-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument` to the `LIBRARY_RELEASE_OPTIONS` this is required to quell the warning with ccache, distcc, etc.

Also, it's best to use `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)` rather than adding `-std=c++14;` to `LIBRARY_RELEASE_OPTIONS`

Comment: would this solve the problem or is this suggestion a best-practice tip?

Comment: This let's CMake decide what is best rather than just consuming a list and passing it on.

Comment: @Crippin updated my answer with something better suited for you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seemed to be related to ccache.
ccache 3.3.3 works as expected while 3.2.4 on ubuntu 16 LTS seems to cause this warning.

Comment: Interesting, is it a known bug? I am using 3.3.4